# JavaScript to find the month difference and calculate with another value

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I am working on a gridview in ASP.NET c#. In gridview if have 4 TextBox in which

```
1st field - hire/month
2nd field - from date
3rd field - to date
4th field - required machine month
```

The concept works like this.

The difference between from_date and to_date should be found in terms of month and it should be multiplied with hire/month to get the required_machine_month field. Please help me on this.

I don't know JavaScript, though I tried my level best by getting the difference in one function and calling the function to another function and multiply it to get the output.

But the JavaScript totally fails and doesn't seem to work. Please provide me a good script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help.. Finally i got the script working. But its a long one. I am posting it below for anyone's use. If anyone are not clear about. Pls feel free to ask so that i can tell what i have done.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function req_mac_month(numbers,fromDate,toDate,mcMonth)
{
    //alert("Executed");
    var reqnum=document.getElementById(numbers).value;
    var sdate=document.getElementById(fromDate).value;
    var edate=document.getElementById(toDate).value;
    //var diff=DisplayTo.getMonth() - DisplayFrom.getMonth() + (12 * (DisplayTo.getFullYear() - DisplayFrom.getFullYear()));
    //var diff=Math.ceil((DisplayTo.getTime()-DisplayFrom.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
    var day1, day2;
    var month1, month2;
    var year1, year2;
    //var noofmonths;
    day1 = sdate.substring(0, sdate.indexOf("-"));
    month1 = sdate.substring(sdate.indexOf("-") + 1, sdate.lastIndexOf("-"));
    year1 = sdate.substring(sdate.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, sdate.length);

    day2 = edate.substring(0, edate.indexOf("-"));
    month2 = edate.substring(edate.indexOf("-") + 1, edate.lastIndexOf("-"));
    year2 = edate.substring(edate.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, edate.length);

    date1 = year1 + "/" + month1 + "/" + day1;
    date2 = year2 + "/" + month2 + "/" + day2;

    firstDate = Date.parse(date1)
    secondDate = Date.parse(date2)

    msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

    dbd = trunc(((Math.round(((secondDate.valueOf() - firstDate.valueOf()) / msPerDay) + 1))/30),4);
            reqmcmonthtotal = dbd * reqnum ;
            document.getElementById(mcMonth).value= reqmcmonthtotal;
    return true;      
}
</script>
```

In the code behind...,

```
TextBox rnum = grvps.FooterRow.FindControl("Ftxteditreqnum") as TextBox;
TextBox fromDate = grvps.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFromDate") as TextBox;
TextBox toDate = grvps.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEndDate") as TextBox;
TextBox mcMonth = grvps.FooterRow.FindControl("Ftxteditreqmcmth") as TextBox;

string req_mac_month = string.Format("return req_mac_month('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}');", rnum.ClientID, fromDate.ClientID, toDate.ClientID, mcMonth.ClientID);
rnum.Attributes.Add("onchange", req_mac_month);
fromDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", req_mac_month);
toDate.Attributes.Add("onchange", req_mac_month);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property in your class that returns computed value and put that property in grid, so there is no need to Javascript. like that:

```
   public string RequiredMachineMonth
   {
       get
       {
            return ... //Your logic based on 'to' and 'from' here
       }
   }
```

Comment: I can do that but inorder to show it instantly when the value is entered, i have to do it in javascript.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood question, I will post an answer as soon as posible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery as an easy way to do it, if you use TemplateField in grid and give your textboxes `class` attribute like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <input type="text" class="to-date"/>
    <ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and assume you have given such classes: `hire-month',`to-date`,`from-date`,`required` then use something like that in jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.to-date, .from-date').change(function(){
            var required = $(this).parent().children('.required');
            var toDate = $(this).parent().children('.to-date').val();
            var fromDate = $(this).parent().children('.from-date').val();
            required.val(toDate + fromDate); //put your logic here
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I you do not use jquery, I'm not good at pure javascript. And i highly recomment jquery, it has a rich ecosystem, with thousands of plugins and it makes javascript programming with DOM structure as you need really easy and fast.

Comment: You mean jquery is not javascript?:D

Comment: He asks for Javasript not jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var DisplayTo = new Date();
var DisplayFrom = new Date("2012-03-05");

var diff = DisplayTo.getMonth() - DisplayFrom.getMonth() + (12 * (DisplayTo.getFullYear() - DisplayFrom.getFullYear()));
var machineMonth = hiremonth * diff;
```

Have you tried this?